# unable to detect reference from leak report by Leakcanary

Tags: android, memory-leaks, leakcanary, memory-leak-detector

```
    below is my leak report captured by leak canary but i am not able to detect from where it keeps referencing object

    * GC ROOT maps.O.n.d
    * references maps.ae.e.i
    * references java.util.ArrayList.array
    * references array java.lang.Object[].[15]
    * references maps.af.a$2.b
    * references maps.af.a.c
    * references maps.af.b.c
    * references maps.af.d.mParent
    * references android.widget.FrameLayout.mParent
    * references com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView.mParent
    * references android.widget.LinearLayout.mParent
    * references android.support.v7.widget.CardView.mParent
    * references android.widget.LinearLayout.mLayoutParams
    * references android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutParams.mViewHolder
    * references com.aimdek.healthwel.adapter.FeedsAdpter$MyViewHolder.this$0
    * references com.aimdek.healthwel.adapter.FeedsAdpter.feedsFragment
    * leaks com.aimdek.healthwel.fragment.FeedsFragment instance

    * Retaining: 1.0 KB.
    * Reference Key: f46244a8-7376-452a-969b-6f19fd070ea2
    * Device: motorola motorola XT1068 titan_retaildsds
    * Android Version: 6.0 API: 23 LeakCanary: 1.4-beta2 3799172
    * Durations: watch=5202ms, gc=259ms, heap dump=13581ms, analysis=108725ms

    * Details:
    * Instance of maps.O.n
    |   static f = java.util.Arrays$ArrayList@315426320 (0x12cd0610)
    |   static $staticOverhead = byte[8]@328672257 (0x13972401)
    |   g = -1
    |   f = false
    |   g = 256
    |   h = java.util.Arrays$ArrayList@315426320 (0x12cd0610)
    |   i = 0
    |   j = 1
    |   k = 2.0
    |   b = maps.O.k@322255648 (0x13353b20)
    |   c = maps.M.ac$i@316399200 (0x12dbde60)
    |   d = maps.ae.e@332202880 (0x13cd0380)
    |   f = null
    |   g = java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock@315427056 (0x12cd08f0)
    |   h = maps.y.m@328083040 (0x138e2660)
    |   i = maps.O.b$3@316588288 (0x12dec100)
    |   j = false
    |   k = maps.O.n$1@315570880 (0x12cf3ac0)
    |   l = java.util.LinkedList@316435840 (0x12dc6d80)
    |   m = maps.O.b$2@316435936 (0x12dc6de0)
    |   n = java.util.HashMap@322255600 (0x13353af0)
    |   o = 3000
    |   p = 0
    |   q = 0
    |   r = 0
    |   s = false
    |   t = java.util.ArrayList@316435904 (0x12dc6dc0)
    |   u = false
    |   v = maps.O.b$1@315427072 (0x12cd0900)
    |   contextClassLoader = dalvik.system.PathClassLoader@315133024 (0x12c88c60)
    |   daemon = false
    |   group = java.lang.ThreadGroup@1869718984 (0x6f71a5c8)
    |   hasBeenStarted = true
    |   id = 9069
    |   inheritableValues = null
    |   interruptActions = java.util.ArrayList@316435584 (0x12dc6c80)
    |   localValues = java.lang.ThreadLocal$Values@316588192 (0x12dec0a0)
    |   lock = java.lang.Object@315427040 (0x12cd08e0)
    |   name = java.lang.String@322255456 (0x13353a60)
    |   nativePeer = -1194656976
    |   parkBlocker = null
    |   parkState = 1
    |   priority = 5
    |   stackSize = 0
    |   target = null
    |   uncaughtHandler = null
    |   shadow$_klass_ = maps.O.n
    |   shadow$_monitor_ = 1267345999
    * Instance of maps.ae.e
    |   static $staticOverhead = byte[24]@331324817 (0x13bf9d91)
    |   static j = java.lang.String@332151648 (0x13cc3b60)
    |   static s = java.util.HashMap@332198576 (0x13ccf2b0)
    |   static a = 
    |   mParentFragment = FriendFragment@317174144 (0x12e7b180)
    |   mReenterTransition = java.lang.Object@326447456 (0x13753160)
    |   mRemoving = false
    |   mRestored = false
    |   mRetainInstance = false
    |   mRetaining = false
    |   mReturnTransition = java.lang.Object@326447456 (0x13753160)
    |   mSavedFragmentState = null
    |   mSavedViewState = android.util.SparseArray@324672992 (0x135a1de0)
    |   mSharedElementEnterTransition = null
    |   mSharedElementReturnTransition = java.lang.Object@326447456 (0x13753160)
    |   mState = 0
    |   mStateAfterAnimating = 0
    |   mTag = null
    |   mTarget = null
    |   mTargetIndex = -1
    |   mTargetRequestCode = 0
    |   mUserVisibleHint = false
    |   mView = null
    |   mWho = null
    |   shadow$_klass_ = com.aimdek.healthwel.fragment.FeedsFragment
    |   shadow$_monitor_ = -2095684492
    * Excluded Refs:
    | Field: android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.mNextServedView
    | Field: android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.mServedView
    | Field: android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.mServedInputConnection
    | Field: android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.mCurRootView
    | Field: android.widget.Editor$Blink.this$0
    | Field: android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.mMessageQueue (always)
Instance of com.aimdek.healthwel.adapter.FeedsAdpter
|   allFeedsList = java.util.ArrayList@326789152 (0x137a6820)
|   context = com.aimdek.healthwel.activity.MainActivity@315004672 (0x12c69700)
|   feedsFragment = com.aimdek.healthwel.fragment.FeedsFragment@315395840 (0x12cc8f00)
|   inflater = com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater@322687328 (0x133bd160)
|   mHasStableIds = false
|   mObservable = android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$AdapterDataObservable@316485552 (0x12dd2fb0)
|   shadow$_klass_ = com.aimdek.healthwel.adapter.FeedsAdpter
|   shadow$_monitor_ = 0
* Instance of com.aimdek.healthwel.fragment.FeedsFragment
|   adapter = com.aimdek.healthwel.adapter.FeedsAdpter@321038624 (0x1322a920)
|   birthday = android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView@332811264 (0x13d64c00)
|   dateformat = java.text.SimpleDateFormat@320969344 (0x13219a80)
|   email = android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView@332332032 (0x13cefc00)
|   feedsId = null
|   friendImg = com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView@332806144 (0x13d63800)
|   friendInfo = null
|   imgBackground = android.widget.LinearLayout@332061696 (0x13cadc00)
|   imgFriendBackground = android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView@329300992 (0x13a0bc00)
|   page = 1
|   profile = android.widget.LinearLayout@332058624 (0x13cad000)
|   recyclerView = com.malinskiy.superrecyclerview.SuperRecyclerView@332813312 (0x13d65400)
|   secondLevel = false
|   tvBirthDate = android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView@332812288 (0x13d65000)
|   tvEmailId = android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView@332335104 (0x13cf0800)
|   tvHeight = android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView@332810240 (0x13d64800)
|   tvName = android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView@332807168 (0x13d63c00)
|   tvWeight = android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView@332326912 (0x13cee800)
|   type = 21
|   userId = java.lang.String@314601152 (0x12c06ec0)
|   activity = com.aimdek.healthwel.activity.MainActivity@315004672 (0x12c69700)
|   mAdded = false
|   mAllowEnterTransitionOverlap = null
|   mAllowReturnTransitionOverlap = null
|   mAnimatingAway = null
|   mArguments = android.os.Bundle@320969440 (0x13219ae0)
|   mBackStackNesting = 0
|   mCalled = true
|   mCheckedForLoaderManager = false
|   mChildFragmentManager = null
|   mContainer = null
|   mContainerId = 0
|   mDeferStart = false
|   mDetached = false
|   mEnterTransition = null
|   mEnterTransitionCallback = null
|   mExitTransition = null
|   mExitTransitionCallback = null
|   mFragmentId = 0
|   mFragmentManager = null
|   mFromLayout = false
|   mHasMenu = true
|   mHidden = false
|   mHost = null
|   mInLayout = false
|   mIndex = -1
|   mInnerView = null
|   mLoaderManager = null
|   mLoadersStarted = false
|   mMenuVisible = false
|   mNextAnim = 0
|   mParentFragment = com.aimdek.healthwel.fragment.FriendFragment@317174144 (0x12e7b180)
|   mReenterTransition = java.lang.Object@326447456 (0x13753160)
|   mRemoving = false
|   mRestored = false
|   mRetainInstance = false
|   mRetaining = false
|   mReturnTransition = java.lang.Object@326447456 (0x13753160)
|   mSavedFragmentState = null
|   mSavedViewState = android.util.SparseArray@324672992 (0x135a1de0)
|   mSharedElementEnterTransition = null
|   mSharedElementReturnTransition = java.lang.Object@326447456 (0x13753160)
|   mState = 0
|   mStateAfterAnimating = 0
|   mTag = null
|   mTarget = null
|   mTargetIndex = -1
|   mTargetRequestCode = 0
|   mUserVisibleHint = false
|   mView = null
|   mWho = null
|   shadow$_klass_ = com.aimdek.healthwel.fragment.FeedsFragment
|   shadow$_monitor_ = -2095684492
```

below is code for FeedsAdapter

```
public class FeedsAdpter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FeedsAdpter.MyViewHolder> {
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private Context context;
    private FeedsFragment feedsFragment;
    private ArrayList<FeedsDto> allFeedsList = new ArrayList<FeedsDto>();


    public FeedsAdpter(Context context, FeedsFragment feedsFragment) {
        this.context = context;
        this.feedsFragment = feedsFragment;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_feeds, parent, false);
        MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(view);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewRecycled(MyViewHolder holder) {
        super.onViewRecycled(holder);
        if(Validator.isNotNull(holder.mapView.getMap())) {
            GoogleMap googleMap = holder.mapView.getMap();
            googleMap.clear();
            googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NONE);
            googleMap=null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final FeedsDto feeds = allFeedsList.get(position);
        GoogleMap googleMap;
        if (Validator.isNotNull(feeds)) {
            if (Validator.isNotNull(feeds.getImagePreviewUrl())) {
                //imageLoader.displayImage(feeds.getImagePreviewUrl(), holder.userImg, HWUtil.IMAGE_OPTIONS);
                Picasso.with(context).setIndicatorsEnabled(true);
                Picasso.with(context)
                        .load(feeds.getImagePreviewUrl())
                        .resize(50,50)
                        .onlyScaleDown()
                        .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                        .error(R.drawable.profile_small_img)
                        .into(holder.userImg);
            } else {
                holder.userImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.profile_small_img);
            }
            holder.tvUserName.setText(feeds.getFullName());
            MainActivity activity = (MainActivity) context;
            String tempMsg = feeds.getFeeds().getMessage();

            if (Validator.isNotNull(feeds.getFeeds().getHistoryId())) {
                if (feeds.getFeeds().getUserId().equals(activity.preferences.getUserInfo().getId())) {
                    tempMsg = tempMsg.replace("[$ACTIVITY_OWNER$]", activity.getResources().getString(R.string.was_out));
                } else {
                    tempMsg = tempMsg.replace("[$ACTIVITY_OWNER$]", activity.getResources().getString(R.string.was_out));
                }
            } else {
                tempMsg = tempMsg.replace("[$ACTIVITY_OWNER$]", "");
            }

            holder.tvMsg.setText(tempMsg);
            if (feeds.isLiked()) {
                holder.likeBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.like_icon_pink);
            } else {
                holder.likeBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.like_icon_grey);
            }
            holder.tvDuration.setText(feeds.getFeedCreatedTime());
            if (Validator.isNotNull(feeds.getFeeds().getHistoryMap()) && feeds.getFeeds().getHistoryMap().length > 0) {
                if (holder.mapView != null) {
                    holder.mapView.onCreate(null);
                    holder.mapView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.mapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
                            if (Validator.isNotNull(googleMap)) {
                                googleMap.clear();
                                holder.mapView.setClickable(false);
                                googleMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(false);
                                List<HistoryMap> historyMaps = new ArrayList<HistoryMap>();
                                historyMaps.addAll(Arrays.asList(feeds.getFeeds().getHistoryMap()));
                                HWUtil.drawRouteIntoMap(historyMaps, googleMap);
                            }
                        }
                    });

                }
            } else {
                holder.mapView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            holder.tvCommentcount.setText(String.valueOf(feeds.getFeeds().getCommentCount()));
            if (feeds.getFeeds().getCommentCount() == 0) {
                holder.commentBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.comment_icon_grey_feeds);
            } else {
                holder.commentBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.comment_icon_feeds);
            }
            holder.tvLikecount.setText(String.valueOf(feeds.getFeeds().getLikeCount()));

            holder.tvPost.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (Validator.isNotNull(holder.etComment.getText().toString())) {
                        hideKeyboard(context);
                        String comment = holder.etComment.getText().toString();
                        feedsFragment.updateComment(feeds.getFeeds().getId(), comment);
                        holder.etComment.setText(HWUtil.BLANK);
                    } else {
                        HWUtil.showToast(context, context.getResources().getString(R.string.enter_comment));
                    }
                }
            });
            holder.likeBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    feedsFragment.updateComment(feeds.getFeeds().getId(), null);
                }
            });
            holder.commentBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    MainActivity activity = (MainActivity) context;
                    activity.setTitle(context.getString(R.string.comment));
                    activity.preferences.setBack(true);
                    activity.preferences.setFeedsDto(feeds);
                    activity.replaceFragment(new CommentFragment(), null);
                }
            });
        }
    }


    public static void hideKeyboard(Context context) {

        try {
            InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

            View view = ((Activity) context).getCurrentFocus();
            if (view != null) {
                inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void addAll(List<FeedsDto> list) {
        allFeedsList.addAll(list);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void clear() {
        allFeedsList = new ArrayList<FeedsDto>();
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return allFeedsList.size();
    }

    public void updateFeeds(String feedsId, com.aimdek.healthwel.dto.Response response, int type) {
        FeedsDto dto = getFeedsDto(feedsId);
        if (Validator.isNotNull(dto)) {
            if (type == Request.LIKE_UNLIKE) {
                dto.getFeeds().setLikeCount(response.getCount());
                dto.setLiked(response.isLiked());
            } else {
                dto.getFeeds().setCommentCount(response.getCount());
            }
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    public FeedsDto getFeedsDto(String feedsId) {
        for (FeedsDto dto : allFeedsList) {
            if (dto.getFeeds().getId().equals(feedsId)) {
                return dto;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        @Bind(R.id.img_user_pic)
        ImageView userImg;
        @Bind(R.id.tv_user_name)
        TextView tvUserName;
        @Bind(R.id.tv_duration)
        TextView tvDuration;
        @Bind(R.id.tv_msg)
        TextView tvMsg;
        @Bind(R.id.workout_map_summary)
        MapView mapView;
        @Bind(R.id.et_feeds_comment)
        EditText etComment;
        @Bind(R.id.tv_post)
        TextView tvPost;
        @Bind(R.id.img_like_btn)
        ImageButton likeBtn;
        @Bind(R.id.img_comment_btn)
        ImageButton commentBtn;
        @Bind(R.id.tv_like_count)
        TextView tvLikecount;
        @Bind(R.id.tv_comment_count)
        TextView tvCommentcount;


        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
        }
    }
}
```

as user likes or comment on particular feeds i invoke fragment class method to update this and i m showing feeds of friend in app.which will create leak when i m showing feeds of individual friend any idea on how to fix this.any help is appriciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should release mNextServedView when the focused window is dismissed(such as onStop or onDestory).

code like :

```
   InputMethodManager methodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    try {
        Field mNextServedView = methodManager.getClass().getDeclaredField("mNextServedView");
        mNextServedView.setAccessible(true);
        mNextServedView.set(methodManager, null);

        Field mServedView = methodManager.getClass().getDeclaredField("mServedView");
        mServedView.setAccessible(true);
        mServedView.set(methodManager, null);

        Method method = methodManager.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("finishInputLocked");
        method.setAccessible(true);
        method.invoke(methodManager);
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: @ muyiou but input method manager that i am using is in Adpater class

Comment: @Hardik Mehta so you should add callback to Adpater